# Allow an authenticated User to Book Multiple Users Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a django website with a booking feature. Now I have created a working website where there is a feature to book a single user (who is logged in). What I want is to allow a logged in user to book multiple of his friends that might not be in the database. I am confused about the model. I know django has a formset for creating multiple similar forms but I want the information of that form to be associated to a single user(who booked them). So what I am thinking regarding model is:

```
class GroupBooking(models.Model):
    booker = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_people = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class UnregisteredUsers(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('GroupBooking',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile = models.CharField()
    # Other Information
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
```

`Number_of_people` could be number of forms created or it could be changed dynamically by adding a button that creates a new form and increments.
I want suggestions regarding my approach and how should I proceed forward. Also I would appreciate some reading material or tutorial covering the features involved in such a process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiSelectField for that specific field like

In case of **models.py**

```
SPORTS_CHOICES = (('cricket','cricket')
                 ('badminton','badminton')
                 ('tennis','tennis'))
sports = MultiSelectField(max_length = 35, choices = CLASS_CHOICES)
```

In case of **forms.py**

```
SPORTS_CHOICES = (('cricket','cricket')
                 ('badminton','badminton')
                 ('tennis','tennis'))
sports = MultiSelectFormField(max_length = 35, choices = CLASS_CHOICES)
```